# How do I implement SVG's into a React project (from Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

I am doing an Advanced CSS course right now, which teaches to implement SVG's. However, it uses Vanilla JS and I want to implement it into a React project.

With Vanilla JS, to implement an SVG into a button, you have to write this:

```
<button class="search__button">
    <svg class="search__icon">
        <use
            xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#icon-magnifying-glass"
        ></use>
    </svg>
</button>
```

However, this code does not work in the React app. I already know that `xlink:href` does not work in React, and has to be changed into `xlinkHref`. Also "class" has to be renamed into "className". However, even when changing this, the SVG does not get rendered.

Why is it so and how can an SVG get rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very experienced with Svgs but The best clean way to do this is by turning the svg into a reusable component

```
    function SVG(props){
    
      return <svg> //put the raw svg code here </svg>
    }

export default SVG;
```

then import it at the file you want to use it like so :

```
import SVG from 'put SVG component (function) path here' ;
```

after importing use it like this:

```
<button> 
<SVG/>
</button>
```

You can also just import the svg like it is a normal image like so :

```
import Svg from 'path to location of raw svg (not the component above)'
```

and use it like this

```
<img src={Svg}>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer :) Your solutions are quite similar to the one's I posted. Your first solution sounds like my second, however, you would make it into a separate component so it can be reused, am I right? Your second solution looks like mine, but you "import" it  from the file location and I simply put it into the img src without importing it. Is there a benefit of your solution?:)

Comment: Hi @MikhailRatner, Turning the svg into a component is the best solution because you avoid being "dry" meaning that you dont repeat yourself, You declare the code only once and if you want to make a change you will make it in one place and it will be reflected everywhere.  About the second part of the question. In my opinion importing it helps with webpack since sometimes simply putting it in the src might fail. Also when you import it you have it as a variable so you can use it in many places in the same file.

Comment: @MikhailRatner Also if you want to change the svg for another one, you could jost change the import path of the file. you change it only once and the changes will be reflected everywhere in that file since you stored it in a variable. If you just pasted the svg like you did and you wanted to exchange it for a new one, you would have to go and change the code manually in all the places. Hope this helped :)

Comment: This is very useful, thanks! Also, yeah I actually had difficulties with webpack and had to adapt the img src to a path that is a bit different than usual. At first your solution seemed a bit more complicated and not necessary for a small project like mine, but I guess it's better to get it right from the beginning.

Comment: Maybe one more thing. A friend of mine made a logo for my project as an svg and I tried to copy-paste the raw svg code into a react component. However, the JSX showed me 223 problems xD The svg also looks a bit different and way longer than other svg's which I downloaded from the internet. But the logo works perfectly when I use it as an img src. Do you have an idea what it could be? Or did you experience something like this before?

Comment: @MikhailRatner I will post is as an answer since I it is too long

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230444/discussion-between-why-u-do-dis-and-mikhailratner).

Comment: I just tried your other option (importing it from the file) but this actually caused an Error:

ERROR in ./client/public/img/SVG/magnifying-glass.svg 2:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently, no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

It seems that this method requires webpack to have a specific loader... which would be a downside for some people who just want to quickly implement an svg. Do you have a specific webpack loader for this?

Comment: @MikhailRatner check this out https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-in-react/#:~:text=SVGs%20can%20be%20imported%20and,%7D%20from%20'.%2Flogo.

Answer (score 0):

I found out two pretty straight-forward solutions. I am not sure if these are the best solutions, but they work.

Please feel free to add further / better solutions. If there is a better one, I will mark it as the best solution :)

**Solution 1**

Using the SVG file as the src of an

```
<button className="search__button">
    <img className="search__icon" src="/img/SVG/magnifying-glass.svg" />
</button>
```

This is IMO the best solution so far, but I ran into problems with it first. My React project uses bundle.js and webpack, which caused the path to be different than I used to be. So if you use this solution but you get a broken img, play around with the path. I tried a lot of versions of the path, e.g. with `../` in the beginning and eventually, this path worked.

**Solution 2**

It is possible to simply copy-paste the code of the SVG into the JSX code. It is definitely not clean, but it works.

```
<button className="search__button">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
<title>magnifying-glass</title>
<path d="M17.545 15.467l-3.779-3.779c0.57-0.935 0.898-2.035 0.898-3.21 0-3.417-2.961-6.377-6.378-6.377s-6.186 2.769-6.186 6.186c0 3.416 2.961 6.377 6.377 6.377 1.137 0 2.2-0.309 3.115-0.844l3.799 3.801c0.372 0.371 0.975 0.371 1.346 0l0.943-0.943c0.371-0.371 0.236-0.84-0.135-1.211zM4.004 8.287c0-2.366 1.917-4.283 4.282-4.283s4.474 2.107 4.474 4.474c0 2.365-1.918 4.283-4.283 4.283s-4.473-2.109-4.473-4.474z"></path>
</svg>
</button>
```